# Monitoring distributed nodes

Tags: erlang, distributed, nagios

We have a Master erlang node that has an application with a supervisor and multiple, dynamically added worker processes. For each worker process, there is another erlang node dynamically started. We would like to monitor all nodes on one screen and detect failures so that corrective action can be taken.

Is there an utility that can let us do this?

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: did you look at pman or appmon (available in erlang distribution),and maybe webtools

Answer (score 0):

I think for almost every erlang distributed application, there is similiar nodes managments requirements. For pman and appmon webtools, I think they are too basic and not enough.

I have read `rabbitmq` source code, there is a website for management and it seems suitable for your requirement.

In addition, I start to read `riak` source code now, the nodes management codes seems better than `rabbitmq`. It is also suitable for your requirement.

I think you could read both of them, and modify based on them and create a new one for your application.

Comment: I found https://github.com/beamspirit/bigwig. But it has no support for monitoring multiple nodes the way appmon does.